# Traveling to UK with expiring Italian residence permit (waiting for renewal)

Tags: visas, uk, italy, us-citizens

I am traveling to the UK for a conference. I am flying from Italy on May 19th and flying back to Italy on May 24th. My permit is valid UNTIL May 24th. Therefore, my permit is still valid on the 24th and this may not even be an issue.

I know I am allowed to enter and leave Italy while my permit is being renewed. I show my expiring/expired permit as well as the postal receipt showing that the renewal is underway and the Italians stamp my receipt..this allows me to enter and leave the country.

However, will I have problems leaving the UK on the 24th? It's still valid, but in case they ask will showing my renewal papers along with the original permit work with the UK as well? (I am an American citizen btw). Thanks!

Comment: If you're leaving on the 24th then why would it be a problem?

Comment: The UK are not going to have a problem with it as long as you can show your outbound flight will arrive on the 24th and your US passport is valid beyond the 24th.  You'll have more problems getting in if anything. But overall nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

So there are four possible 'issues' points:

- leaving Italy.  As you've said, you're allowed to leave and enter Italy while renewal is proceeding. So that's fine.  And they might ask for a flight out of the UK, to prove you intend on leaving the UK.
- entering the UK. As long as you have evidence that you're leaving again, that should be fine.
- leaving the UK. The airline may have to ensure you're legally allowed to enter Italy.  As an American, you could enter as a tourist or on your currently valid permit (until the end of the 24th). Of course, if your flight is delayed/cancelled, this might be a problem...consider that.  They may ask about the expiring permit, but as you'll have the paperwork/proof of the renewal with you (right?), you'll be able to assure them of the legality.
- arriving in Italy once more. Provided your permit is still valid or has been renewed, you'll be fine.  Failing that, you may have to enter as a tourist, but that could be tricky given your recent history there on a permit.